# my code is working fine with the API in localhost but when i host it, it fetch wrong URL it include the web name. How can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs

in browser developer console it display
GET https://food-recipe-finder.000webhostapp.com/www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a

it should be
https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a

this is my code,

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a');

useEffect(() => {
fetch(url).then(res=> res.json()).then(data=>{
setItem(data.meals);
})
},[url])

 const setIndex = (alpha) => {
        setUrl(`https:/www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=${alpha}`)
    }

    const enterRecipe = (e) =>{
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {      
        setUrl(`https:/www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${e.currentTarget.value}`)        
        e.currentTarget.blur();
      }  
    }
```

Comment: Typo.  Your URLs are using one forward slash after the protocol instead of two.  `https:/` should be `https://`